# JS - beforeunload does not fire when I navigate out of current page?

Tags: javascript

I have an ASP.NET web forms app that contains a confirm dialog that I have successfully made to trigger when I navigate within the page.  I have the page prompting the user to give confirmation to save or cancel changes.  When I navigate to another link, the page does not trigger the confirmation message.

I am trying to get the following event to trigger but it only works on new requests on the "Same" page such as pressing next, back, previous, first.  When I click on a menu on the page to load a new page I do not see beforeunload firing.

How can I modify the following code to provide the same confirmation when I navigate to another link by clicking on a menu in ASP.NET?

```
 $(window).on("beforeunload", function () {

                if ((updateCancelClicked == false) && ($("#MainContent_ErrorContent").text() != "No Action Items Found.") &&
                       ($("#FormChanged").val() == "true") || ($("#MainContent_btnUpdateItem").is(":disabled") == false) &&
                                                         ($("#MainContent_btnCancelItem").is(":disabled") == false)) {

                    if ((!firstConfirm || $("#MainContent_btnUpdateItem").is(":enabled")) && $("#MainContent_ConfirmAlertOn").val() == "True") 
                    {
                        firstConfirm = true;
                        confirmVal = confirm("Save changes? \"OK\" saves changes. \"Cancel\" removes changes.");
                    }
                    if (confirmVal) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ViewEditActionItem.aspx/UpdateFormData",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ actionItemID: $.trim($("#MainContent_txtActionItemID").val()), assignedDate: $.trim($("#MainContent_txtAssignedDate").val()), originalDueDate: $.trim($("#MainContent_txtOriginalDueDate").val()), ECD: $.trim($("#MainContent_txtECD").val()), ClosedDate: $.trim($("#MainContent_txtClosedDate").val()), criticality: $.trim($("#MainContent_ddlCriticality").val()), category1: $.trim($("#MainContent_ddlCategory1").val()), category2: $.trim($("#MainContent_ddlCategory2").val()), ownerUserID: $.trim($("#MainContent_ddlOwner").val()), altOwnerUserID: $.trim($("#MainContent_ddlAltOwner").val()), actionItemTitle: $.trim($("#MainContent_txtActionItemTitle").val()), progressID: $.trim($("#MainContent_ddlProgress").val()), actionItemStatement: $.trim($("#MainContent_txtActionItemStatement").val()), closureStatement: $.trim($("#MainContent_txtClosureStatement").val()), closureCriteria: $.trim($("#MainContent_txtClosureCriteria").val()), notes: $.trim($("#MainContent_txtNotes").val()) }),
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {

                    $("#MainContent_ConfirmAlertOn").val("True");
                    return;
                }
            });
```

Comment: There are many restrictions on what the `beforeunload` handler is allowed to do.

Comment: It appears that the behavior is observed in Firefox and not IE.  Are there any ways to workaround this security feature in Firefox?